# Database service to replace Google Sheets

Tags: database, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, cloud, google-cloud-datastore

I am using Google Sheets to create a database that is connected to Google Data Studio. But the database is growing fast and will soon overgrow Sheets limits.
I am looking for a cloud service that is simple to use like Sheets, where I can manually add data, do calculations (like formulas in Sheets) and also use Python to update the data there. I also need it to connect to Google Data Studio for visualisation.

I got recommended Firestore, Cloud SQL, Bigquery, but I still do not understand the difference between them. I am looking for something cheap where I can do the things I mentioned above.
P.S. I am new to SQL, so I would prefer a visual database (like Sheets).

Thank you all!

Answer (score 0):

Sheet is not a database, but you can use as is. You have other type of database on Google Cloud, such as

- Firestore a document oriented database, not really similar to a tabular Sheet
- BigQuery which is a datawarehouse very powerful and the most similar to sheet in its design, checks and controls
- Cloud SQL hosts relational database engine, similar to BigQuery but with, in addition, the capacity to create contraint (unique value, primary key, external (foreign) key in relation with another value in another table.

However, no one offer the easiness of Sheet in term of graphical interface. The engine are powerful but are developer oriented and not desktop user oriented.

Comment: Considering the OP's use case, I would suggest Cloud SQL as the most fitting. recalculating data in mass is not advisable for Firestore.